api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-1.dll is missing, when i run my app (written in c++) in windows 8.1
I done app in c++ in visual studio in windows 10, it worked good without errors. When i ran app in windows 8.1 (with needed files for app of course) i had error that api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-1.dll is missing. I downloaded this file and also some files but i have same error and so. What i need to do? Compiling the app in windows 8.1 would be problem for me, but i may try. But better for me to know, how i need to compile this for i haven't errors
I tried to download needed files, which was missing in the error. But i have error and so

Simply use kernel32.lib instead lib which you use
